# How to get facebook post permalink

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using Facebook's Open Graph API to get a list of posts, what we get is a post id like XXXX_YYYY which can be converted to facebook.com/XXXX/posts/YYYY

But these links cannot be used with the facebook embed plugin : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

Eg - https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=229021587215556&id=11239244970&stream_ref=10 works, but https://www.facebook.com/11239244970/posts/229021587215556 doesn't, even when both the URLs load the same post.

How can I fetch the permalink for a post so that it can be used in the embed box.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong because both works with the embedded posts plugin :) and here's an example (check the source) you will see that `data-href` is in `http://facebook.com/{user}/{postId}` format http://retrogram.eu/demos/adamsposts/

Comment: @Adam Azad : Here's how I see those posts : http://i.imgur.com/VpuzLtT.png

Comment: I'm not sure it solve your problem or not, but you can get permalink via FQL, e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20permalink%20from%20stream%20where%20post_id%3D'11239244970_229021587215556'

Comment: well, that's because I used an app access token (privacy issues), but as you can that format works pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As answered by 林果皞](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670773/how-to-get-facebook-post-permalink#comment34550888_22670773):

The best way seems to be using facebook's [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20permalink%20from%20stream%20where%20post_id%3D%2711239244970_229021587215556%27).